# VIM : How to map command according to buffer type?

Tags: windows, vim

I know my title is not that descriptive/clear so let me explain.

Yesterday I can across `Vimgrep and copen` so I added the below line in `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <silent> ,/ :execute 'vimgrep /'.@/.'/g %'<CR>:copen<CR>
```

What it does is open a `quickfix list` for the `searched(highlighted)` word in vim.

Now when you press `Enter<CR>` in quickfix list it takes you to a corresponding line in the main Vim Window.

Now, the problem I am facing is I have mapped my `<CR` like `map <CR> o<Esc>` which creates a new line just below the current line.

So, as you can see there is a conflict b/w the two. So, what I am trying is to come up with a vim function like

*Pseudo Code*

```
function IfNotInsideQuickFix()
    if buffer != QuickFix
        then map <CR> o<Esc>
    elif buffer == QuickFix
         Normal behaviour

Call function
```

Here is the output of `:buffers`

```
:buffers
  1 #a   "test.cs"                      line 0
  2 %a-  "[Quickfix List]"              line 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have no experience in writing vim functions. So, can someone please guide me to it.

PS: I know that I can change my Vim mapping to create a new line but I want to learn how to do it via Vim function

Comment: Have you tried autocmd and then map there your shortcuts?

Comment: @tuxtimo: I have no idea on how to do that. If you can give me a start than I can work on it. I looked at `:h autocmd` but could't figure out on how to use it in my case.

Comment: can you detect wheter it is a quickfix file or not with the filetype?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can keep your global `<CR>` mapping as-is, but locally in quickfix windows restore the original behavior. This is done via an `:autocmd` (triggered when the quickfix window opens) that maps (without remapping) `<CR>` (locally via `<buffer>`) onto itself.

```
:autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you please explain/elaborate your solution so that I can learn from it.

Comment: I thought I had explained everything already; I've made it more verbose and explicit. You can read up on everything via `:help <topic>`; the Vim help is excellent. And keep cool; the learning curve is steep initially :-)

Comment: I was trying add the autocmd to my vimrc, but it doesn't find the quickfix buffer. `autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>` should I use `BufReadPost *fix*` instead?